# AngularJS HTML filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app, I need to have the string to be filtered (with a filter) to show the correct HTML formatting:

This:

```
$scope.text = "This is <strong>GREAT</strong>";
```

Needs to be:

> This is **GREAT**

(And other HTML tags, like `<br>` and so forth should be working)

It should work thru a **filter**, like:

```
{{text | toHTML}}
```

I know about `ng-bind-html` BUT I need it to work thru a filter and NOT with `ng-bind-html`.

I found some examples where the filter needs to be constructed for each step (for the `<a>` there is a code, for `<br>` another one...)

Is there a way to filter a scope element to handle the HTML formatting?

Comment: Have you included `ngSanitize` in your angular module?

Comment: You can't do that ... interpolation only inserts text...not html

Comment: You can with `$sce.trustAsHtml` as explain in the answers below, but beware that the html you display is trusted and doesn't come from a user. Otherwise it's a high risk of XSS flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is....this can not be done and is why `ngBindHtml` exists in the first place

You are asking to change the default internal compiling of `{{}}` from inserting text nodes to inserting html elements

Regardless of what you define inside `{{}}` you can't change the fact that it will always be inserted as a text node and any html tags inside it will not be converted to dom elements.

There is a good XSS security reason for this behavior also. By inserting as text it prevents insertion of malicious script, iframe etc from user input or corrupted data sources

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter that returns `$sce.trustAsHtml`ed input as output.

Something like:

```
.filter('toHTML', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
}])
```

**EDIT**: if you can only use `{{}}` to render, I am afraid this won't help you. Maybe you can create a `directive` that does the `element` level modifications for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create this filter as below

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
        return function(val) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        };
    });
```

Use the filter like this

```
<p ng-bind-html="textCmt | unsafe"></p>
```

Comment: I CANNOT use `ng-bind-html` has to be as a filter in curly braces as wrote above.

Comment: @Mr.Web you can not change the fact that `{{}}` only inserts text. There is no workaround that would make it insert html. That is why `ng-bind-html` exists

Comment: @charlietfl ! This is a good answer. "`There is no workaround that would make it insert html`". Please answer my question with this answer and the reasons why so I can tick it.